# .Net Core 6 web api Cors

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a web api in .net core 6
What I want is to enable cors from all origins.
when I add policy just for localhost it works fine, but when I change my policy to allow any origin, I get the error -
Access to XMLHttpRequest at '...' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

My code:

```
...
/* NOT working */
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "any",
        policy =>
        {
            policy
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials();
        });
});

/* Works fine*/
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "local",
        policy =>
        {
            policy
            .WithOrigins("http://localhost")
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials();
        });
});


...


app.UseCors("any");
/* OR */
app.UseCors("local");
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ConfigureServices` put:

```
services.AddCors();
```

and in `Configure` put:

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                              .AllowAnyHeader()
                              .AllowAnyMethod());
```

Comment: I'm using core 6 so I don't have thos functions. I only have the program.cs file. I added services.AddCors(); and that worked. Thanks!